# How to compare DateTime without time via LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datetime

I have

```
var q = db.Games.Where(t => t.StartDate >= DateTime.Now).OrderBy(d => d.StartDate);
```

But it compares including time part of `DateTime`. I really don't need it.

**How to do it without time?**

Thank you!

Comment: The compared value (`DateTime.Now`) is supplied statically.  If it's simply replaced by `DateTime.Today` *nothing has to be truncated*. It's incredible that so many answers with some form of truncating `t.StartDate` have been posted. It seems that people stop reading after "DateTime without time".

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Just use `DateTime.Today` property to take the current date. There's no need to truncate `t.StartDate` in this case (and doing so may incur performance penalties).

```
var today = DateTime.Today;

var q = db.Games.Where(t => t.StartDate >= today)
                .OrderBy(t => t.StartDate);
```

Note that I've explicitly evaluated `DateTime.Today` *once* so that the query is consistent - otherwise each time the query is executed, and even *within* the execution, `Today` could change, so you'd get inconsistent results. For example, suppose you had data of:

```
Entry 1: March 8th, 8am
Entry 2: March 10th, 10pm
Entry 3: March 8th, 5am
Entry 4: March 9th, 8pm
```

Surely either *both* entries 1 and 3 should be in the results, or *neither* of them should... but if you evaluate `DateTime.Today` and it *changes* to March 9th after it's performed the first two checks, you could end up with entries 1, 2, 4.

Of course, using `DateTime.Today` assumes you're interested in the date in the *local* time zone. That may not be appropriate, and you should make *absolutely* sure you know what you mean. You *may* want to use `DateTime.UtcNow.Date` instead, for example. Unfortunately, [`DateTime` is a slippery beast](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html)...

EDIT: You may also want to get rid of the calls to `DateTime` static properties altogether - they make the code hard to unit test. In [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) we have an interface specifically for this purpose ([`IClock`](http://noda-time.googlecode.com/hg/docs/api/html/T_NodaTime_IClock.htm)) which we'd expect to be injected appropriately. There's a "system time" implementation for production and a "stub" implementation for testing, or you can implement it yourself.

You can use the same idea without using Noda Time, of course. To unit test this particular piece of code you may want to pass the date in, but you'll be getting it from *somewhere* - and injecting a clock means you can test *all* the code.

Comment: +1. "may need to use Utc" is good point. In addition to caching value of "now" it would be better to pass it as argument to a function so you can unit test it (testing code with DateTime.Today/DateTime.Now is not easy).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Or inject a clock, yes. Will add that.

Comment: The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: @SAR: Indeed - I'd expect to see something in `SqlFunctions` for this, but I can't see it...

Comment: @JonSkeet Actully i want to compare to date(now and given date) with out time in MVC5 i could not fine any solution in my case or i count not understand the solutions to implement, any idia in linq to compare only tow date with out time , thanks

Comment: @SAR: The MVC part is irrelevant, and "in LINQ" is too vague: you specifically mean "in Entity Framework". A quick search found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539224 - it sounds like you want `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime`.

Comment: If `t.StartDate.Date >= today`, then also `t.StartDate >= today`. It seems to me that all these truncating solutions that have piled up under this question aren't necessary, which is esp. relevant when looking for the right way to make an ORM truncate dates in SQL. Am I missing something?

Comment: @GertArnold: Yes, I agree. Will remove it. Although I doubt that it'll be *particularly* relevant 10 years after the question was asked...

Comment: Apparently people keep finding it. And it's *your* answer :). I forgot to mention (although it's obvious to you) that not truncating `t.StartDate` is esp. relevant in a database setting because the query wil be sargable.

Answer (score 134):

The Date property is not supported by LINQ to Entities -- you'll get an error if you try to use it on a DateTime field in a LINQ to Entities query. You can, however, trim dates using the DbFunctions.TruncateTime method.

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
var q = db.Games.Where(t => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(t.StartDate) >= today);
```

Comment: Just a note, `EntityFunctions` has now been replaced by `DbFunctions` in later versions of the Entity Framework

Comment: I'm the only one that your solution and the solution of Jon raise me the error "The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities" ?

Comment: After seeing this for the first time, it looks like System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions has a number of useful other methods as well.  Very helpful!

Comment: Don't use dynamic or "var" if you don't need it.

Answer (score 20):

Try this code

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
var q = db.Games.Where(t => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(t.StartDate) <= today);
```

Answer (score 12):

I found that in my case this is the only way working: (in my application I want to remove old log entries)

```
 var filterDate = dtRemoveLogs.SelectedDate.Value.Date;
 var loadOp = context.Load<ApplicationLog>(context.GetApplicationLogsQuery()
              .Where(l => l.DateTime.Year <= filterDate.Year
                       && l.DateTime.Month <= filterDate.Month
                       && l.DateTime.Day <= filterDate.Day));
```

I don't understand why the Jon's solution is not working ....

Comment: Why are you comparing the `Month` property of one `DateTime` to the `Year` property of the other?

Comment: Awesome solution. Worked for me in implementing date column comparing in Web API!!! Surprisingly after 5 years also it helped me that is more great.

Comment: Great... smart and simply idea

Answer (score 10):

It happens that LINQ doesn't like properties such as `DateTime.Date`. It just can't convert to SQL queries. So I figured out a way of comparing dates using Jon's answer, but without that naughty `DateTime.Date`. Something like this:

`var q = db.Games.Where(t => t.StartDate.CompareTo(DateTime.Today) >= 0).OrderBy(d => d.StartDate);`

This way, we're comparing a full database DateTime, with all that date and time stuff, like 2015-03-04 11:49:45.000 or something like this, with a DateTime that represents the actual first millisecond of that day, like 2015-03-04 00:00:00.0000.

Any DateTime we compare to that `DateTime.Today` will return us safely if that date is later or the same. Unless you want to compare literally the same day, in which case I think you should go for Caesar's answer.

The method `DateTime.CompareTo()` is just fancy Object-Oriented stuff. It returns -1 if the parameter is earlier than the DateTime you referenced, 0 if it is LITERALLY EQUAL (with all that timey stuff) and 1 if it is later.

Answer (score 2):

The `.Date` answer is misleading since you get the error mentioned before. Another way to compare, other than mentioned `DbFunctions.TruncateTime`, may also be:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now.date;
var q = db.Games.Where(t => SqlFunctions.DateDiff("dayofyear", today, t.StartDate) <= 0
      && SqlFunctions.DateDiff("year", today, t.StartDate) <= 0)
```

It looks better(more readable) in the generated SQL query. But I admit it looks worse in the C# code XD. I was testing something and it seemed like `TruncateTime` was not working for me unfortunately the fault was between keyboard and chair, but in the meantime I found this alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var q = db.Games.Where(t => t.StartDate.Date >= DateTime.Now.Date).OrderBy(d => d.StartDate);
```

Comment: See my answer for why that's not a good idea; also, DateTime.Today is a simpler approach.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Good point. Didn't catch that. That's exactly one of those bugs that would never happen during the development (because you're probably testing during the day) and instead will come back and haunt you later!

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dt=DateTime.Now.date;

var q = db.Games.Where(
    t =>EntityFunction.TruncateTime(t.StartDate.Date >=EntityFunction.TruncateTime(dt)).OrderBy(d => d.StartDate
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while I was stuck with the same query. I finally found it without using DbFunctions. 
Try this:

> var q = db.Games.Where(t => t.StartDate.Day == DateTime.Now.Day && t.StartDate.Month == DateTime.Now.Month && t.StartDate.Year == DateTime.Now.Year ).OrderBy(d => d.StartDate);

This way by bifurcating the date parts we effectively compare only the dates, thus leaving out the time.

Hope that helps. Pardon me for the formatting in the answer, this is my first answer.

Comment: Pronlem is when you have same column involved in more than one filtering predicates you'll end up with one being picked as seek predicate and the rest become residual predicates