# Entity framework group by date and return new class

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm using the .NET and the Entity Framework.
I want to group a table by a date without the time part.

I've got the class:

```
public sealed class QueryItem {
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }
}
```

And the method (I'm using the BLToolkit, if you want to know what is DbManager):

```
protected override IQueryable<QueryItem> InitiateQuery() {
    return
        from query in DbManager.GetTable<SomeTableModel>()
        group query by new { Year = query.CreationDate.Year, Month = query.CreationDate.Month, Day = query.CreationDate.Day }
        into list1
        select new QueryItem {Year = list1.Key.Year, Month = list1.Key.Month, Day = list1.Key.Day};
}
```

In this method linq translated into this SQL query:

```
SELECT
    [query].[CreationDate]
FROM
    [SomeDatabase.SomeTable] [query]
GROUP BY
    DatePart(Year, [query].[CreationDate]),
    DatePart(Month, [query].[CreationDate]),
    DatePart(Day, [query].[CreationDate]),
    [query].[CreationDate]
```

And this is wrong query because it doesn't group only by a date.

But if I use this code (it's not usable, I need to return a class object):

```
var result =
    from query in DbManager.GetTable<SomeTableModel>()
    group query by new { Year = query.CreationDate.Year, Month = query.CreationDate.Month, Day = query.CreationDate.Day }
    into list1
    select list1;
```

It will be translated into this:

```
SELECT
    [t1].[c1] as [c11],
    [t1].[c2] as [c21],
    [t1].[c3] as [c31]
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            DatePart(Year, [selectParam].[CreationDate]) as [c1],
            DatePart(Month, [selectParam].[CreationDate]) as [c2],
            DatePart(Day, [selectParam].[CreationDate]) as [c3]
        FROM
            [SomeDatabase.SomeTable] [selectParam]
    ) [t1]
GROUP BY
    [t1].[c1],
    [t1].[c2],
    [t1].[c3]
```

And this is the right query.

I suppose that Entity Framework trying to optimise my query or something like this and this is why I've got the wrong query.

Am I right?
Am I doing it in the right way?
What should I do (maybe use direct SQL query or something else)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is much simpler to use [EntityFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.aspx)* here:

```
var result =
    from query in DbManager.GetTable<SomeTableModel>()
    group query by EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(query.CreationDate)
    into list1
    select list1;
```

<sup>*[DbFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.aspx) as of Entity Framework 6.</sup>

Comment: I suppose it should work. But it failed with BLToolkit.  
The exception message:  
_'TruncateTime(Convert(selectParam.CreationDate))' cannot be converted to SQL._  
And the stacktrace:  
_   at BLToolkit.Data.Linq.Builder.ExpressionBuilder.ConvertToSql(IBuildContext context, Expression expression, Boolean unwrap)_  
I should think how to realize UI of the filter in another way.

Comment: In EF it translates to `convert (datetime, convert(varchar(255), [DateField], 102) ,  102))`. Can you use that to create some function in BLT? It's not clear to me how BLT and EF cooperate. BLT documentation is really poor, sadly.

Comment: I tried to implement my own comparer. It's failed too. It's always try to optimise the query and failed.  
But I used another UI & a way for filter a data and now everything is working.

Answer (score 5):

**Update answer:**  `EntityFunctions` got deprecated.

> Warning    1   'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityFunctions' is obsolete: 'This class has been replaced by System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.'    c:\users\liufa\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\MatasMrLenderTest\Mvc5MobileApplication1\Controllers\CreditScoreController.cs  32  103 Mvc5MobileApplication1

Now it's `DbFunctions`.

```
using System.Data.Entity;

var result = DbManager.GetTable<SomeTableModel>()
.GroupBy(o => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(o.CreationDate))
```