# How to Solve Linq Incorrect Date Query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have 2 textboxes to get DateTime.

For example i have today's values on my database and other DateTime values.

When i choose today's date to query, i can't get the today's Date values from database to show. If i choose tomorrow i can get what i want.

I mean when i choose 01.01.2014 - 09.12.2014 - i can get 8 data.(it's incorrect)
If i choose 01.01.2014 - 10.12.2014 - i can get 17 data(it's correct)

So i can not get "8" -  09.12.2014 date data even i choose 09.12.2014.

Is there a problem with my query?

```
   @Html.TextBox("min", min, "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", new { @class = "date", id = "min", @readonly = "true" }) 

   @Html.TextBox("max", max, "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", new { @class = "date", id = "max", @readonly = "true" })
```

My model property:

```
public DateTime DateTime{ get; set; }
```

My query:

```
  model= (MyBL.GetAllValues().Where(a => a.DateTime>= min && a.DateTime<= max && a.DeptId== myDeptId)).ToList();
```

Comment: Well any date that is today and a few minutes will be greater than today so you will need to add 1 day to the date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably caused by the fact that `max` = `09.12.2014 0:00`, i.e. midnight. so `09.12.2014 1:00` for example is after `max`. You probably want to only compare the dates, you may try this:

```
MyBL.GetAllValues().Where(a => a.DateTime.Date >= min.Date && a.DateTime.Date <= max.Date && a.DeptId== kullanicininBirimi)
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer above will throw an exception since Date property is not supported by LINQ to Entities. You can use EntityFunctions.TruncateTime method. See answers [How to compare DateTime without time via LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626348/how-to-compare-datetime-without-time-via-linq) and [The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597373/the-specified-type-member-date-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities-exception)