# How to filter data from date in Asp .Net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, lambda

I have stored data in Sql Server and date is stored in this format `2016-07-25 08:57:03.483` and datatype i given is `datetime`.

Now i want to filter data from database using date.

```
string startDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00");
string endDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd 23:59:59");
DateTime startDate1 = DateTime.Parse(startDate);
DateTime endDate1 = DateTime.Parse(endDate);

ViewBag.billHistory = db.tbl_electricity.
Where(x.INSRT_TMSP>= startDate1 && x.INSRT_TMSP<= endDate1).ToList();
```

But data is not filtering What i did wrong ?

Comment: sqlserver data type is datetime or varchar?

Comment: datetime data type

Comment: try DateTime endDate1 = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59).AddSeconds(59);

Comment: and DateTime startDate1 = DateTime.Now.Date;

Comment: hello @nazark, i did as you suggest answer, endDate1 gives me `24/07/2016 00:00:00`  but stored datetime in database is `2016-07-24 08:57:03.483`. So data is not filtering. should i change datatype in database  ?

Comment: i checked in database, datatype is datetime.

Comment: i am using sql server 2014, is this issue ?

Comment: As with nazark I would use DateTime.Today.AddHours(23).....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If db values content a time part which needs to be ignored, you should compare only date parts as

```
ViewBag.billHistory = db.tbl_electricity.
Where(x.INSRT_TMSP.Date>= startDate1 && x.INSRT_TMSP.Date<= endDate1).ToList();
```

See [How to compare DateTime without time via LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626348/how-to-compare-datetime-without-time-via-linq)

If time is never required, simply change the data type in the database from *datetime* to *date*.