# EF Core to SQL group by date without time can't be translated to SQL

Tags: linq, date, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

Using .NET 6 and EF Core, I have this code:

```
var FileSizeMB_Grouped =
   _db.FileSizeMBs.GroupBy(x => x.CreatedDate.Date);
```

I get this error from it:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet().GroupBy(x => x.CreatedDate.Date)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

I know the reason, if I use `.AsEnumerable()`, it works fine because can't be translated to SQL, but...

Is there any way to translate this to SQL directly without using `AsEnumerable` or `RawSqlQuery` ?

I have read a lot of posts like these:

- [DbFunctions.TruncateTime LINQ equivalent in EF CORE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40758784/dbfunctions-truncatetime-linq-equivalent-in-ef-core)
- [How to compare DateTime without time via LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626348/how-to-compare-datetime-without-time-via-linq)

But...

- `.Date property` can't be translated
- `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` can't be found
- `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EF.Functions` can't be found
- `EF.Property<DateTime>(x.CreatedDate, "dt").Date` can't be translated

Comment: It has nothing to do with dates. The whole `GroupBy` construct (without key/aggregates projection) is not supported. See [Complex Query Operators - GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#groupby)

Comment: @IvanStoev Ok, fixed, using `where and select` after `group by`, and it can be traslated, thanks